# Combining Textual, Categorical and Numerical data for Semantic Search using SentenceTransformers model

Tags: nlp, categorical-data, bert, embeddings, search

I'm building a food semantic search model and I want to use a pre-trained [SentenceTransformers](https://www.sbert.net/examples/applications/semantic-search/README.html) model with cosine similarity. I'm using [Epicurious](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/hugodarwood/epirecipes/data?select=full_format_recipes.json) dataset for the corpus which consists of textual ("title", "description", "directions") as well as categorical ("categories") and numerical data ("calories", "fat", "sodium").

The model that computes embeddings for the corpus takes `String` data as an input. So my idea was to combine the categorical and numerical data with textual data in a single `String`.

Do you think it's a right way to handle categorical data? If yes, what are the ways to concatenate such data (maybe using column names with the values or adding some tags)? Otherwise, what is a better way to handle such data?